# Why is open graph image cropping when webpage is shared on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've spent HOURS on this...

The page below reports no problems when checked in the Facebook debugger tool - if I click on the thumbnail shown beside the og:image it shows my 1200x630 image, which should be plenty large enough and with the correct scaling that they recommend...

But when I share that page on Facebook, the image is heavily cropped!

http://fairshareplan.com/community/episode-3/index.html

What in the world is going on here?